# how to display image onclick inside a jinja loop?

Tags: html, jinja2, fastapi

I'm quietly new to jinja and need to parse the "attachment" variable inside the loop to the rendered partial HTML template on clicking the attachment name.

the partial page includes the dive HTML to display this attachment using img tag.
and the attachment variable includes the file name.

**profile.html**

```
<div class="tab-pane fade" id="attachment-tab-pane" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="attachment-tab" tabindex="0">
    <a class="btn" role="button" id="btn-add-attachment" data-bs-toggle="modal" data-bs-target="#upload-attachment-modal">+ Add Attachment</a>
    <div id="attachments" class="p-4">
        <div class="row gx-3">
            {% for attachment in attachments %}
                <div class="col-12 col-lg-6">
                    <div class="d-flex justify-content-between attachment-item">
                            <div class="start"><i class="fas fa-file-alt me-3"></i>
<span type="button" class="popos_img" id="button_{{attachment}}">{{attachment}}</span></div>
                        <div class="end"><i class="fas fa-eye me-2"></i>
                            <i class="fas fa-trash me-2"></i><i class="fas fa-cloud-download-alt"></i></div>           
                    </div>
                </div>
<!-- Modal -->
<div hidden class="modal fade"
    id="view_attachment_modal"
    tabindex="-1"
    role="dialog"
    aria-labelledby="exampleModalLabel"
    aria-hidden="true" style="text-align: center;">

    <div class="modal-dialog" role="document" style="margin: auto;text-align: center;">
        <div class="modal-content" style="display:table;text-align: center;">

            <!-- Add image inside the body of modal -->
            <div class="modal-body" style="text-align: center;">
                <img id="image" src="/assets/img/{{attachment}}" alt="Click an attachment" />
            </div>

            <div class="modal-footer">
                <button type="button"
                    class="btn btn-secondary"
                    data-dismiss="modal">
                    Close
            </button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
            {% endfor %}
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

what's happening is only one attachment keeps displaying on click across all attachments.

What I do expect is when clicking any attachment name It shows up.

I am sure there's something missing.
Thanks in advance

**EDIT**

I tried this JQuery Snippet but it didn't work, what's wrong with it?

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {          
        $('.button').each(function(){
            $(this).click(function(){
                $('#view_attachment_modal'+$(this).attr('attachment')).toggle();
            });
        });
    });
</script>
```

Comment: You're only including the attachment modal _at the end of your template_. At that time the value represented by `ns.attachment` is the last iteration of the loop. You'll either have to create a modal inside your loop, make a javascript function that fetches values from `data-` attributes and builds a modal, or fetch the relevant details about an attachment (with `fetch` through an API endpoint for attachments) when the user selects an attachment.

Comment: First hide all images on render, and select all elements with query selector and add an onclick, whichever is clicked change the display to show this is if you want it all to load on page load, else ajax request to fetch only images needed

Comment: @KaviHarjani Thanks for your comment.. I have updated the post as to I made the image content div as hidden and moved inside the for loop and added the JQuery snippet I tried, however it doesn't work..

Comment: @MatsLindh I tried to add onclick event to the span and created a javascript function that expects the attachment name, however It didn't work.. Could you show me how to handle this in javascript?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay so as @MatsLindh's comment said, it solved my case.
There's no need for javascript or Jquery here, as creating unique modals on a length of the array has solved this issue. Which make perfect sense.

So the code should be like this:

```
{% for attachment in attachments %}
    <div class="col-12 col-lg-6">                        
        <div class="d-flex justify-content-between attachment-item">
            <div class="start"><i class="fas fa-file-alt me-3"></i><a class="btn" role="button" data-bs-toggle="modal" data-bs-target="#view-attachment-{{attachment.id}}"><span>{{attachment.attachment}}</span></a></div>

        </div>
    </div>  
<!-- Modal -->
<div class="modal fade"
    id="view-attachment-{{attachment.id}}"
    tabindex="-1"
    role="dialog"
    aria-labelledby="exampleModalLabel"
    aria-hidden="true">

    <div class="modal-dialog modal-dialog-centered" role="document" style="position: relative;display: table;overflow-y: auto;overflow-x: auto;width: auto;min-width: 300px;max-width: 80%;">
        <div class="modal-content">
        <div class="modal-header">
          <h5 class="modal-title">{{attachment}}</h5>
          </button>
        </div>
            <!-- Add image inside the body of modal -->
            
            <div class="modal-body">
                <img id="image" src="/assets/img/{{name}}_Attachments/{{attachment}}" alt="Click an attachment" style="max-width: 100%;"/>
            </div>

            <div class="modal-footer">
                <button type="button"
                    class="btn btn-secondary"
                    data-bs-dismiss="modal">
                    Close
            </button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div> 
                                
{% endfor %}
```

Answer (score 1):

"." operator is used for class, "#" is for ID, you don't have any button class, for tag references it's just the name so "button" in your case, but doing this it will work on all buttons, do remember that

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {          
        $('button').each(function(){
            $(this).click(function(){
                $('#view_attachment_modal'+$(this).attr('attachment')).toggle();
            });
        });
    });
</script>
```